# Any way to enable Google Drive search in dash without other online results?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

As you probably know, ticking the "do not include online results" option in Security and Privacy prevents the Google Drive scope from returning results; unticking it opens the floodgates and provides results from Soundcloud, DuckDuckGo, etc. etc., even though I don't have any other online scope packages installed.

Is there any officially supported way to selectively enable only certain online results (in my case, only Google Drive)? Uninstalling the packages I don't want doesn't seem to be doing it...